# Create column span when booking timeslot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I was playin' around for a few hours, but didn't find a good solution, so that's why I came up here.

Right now I'm trying to display a table with different time slots (08:00-08:30|08:30-09:00|09:00-10:30.. a.s.o) on the rows and employees on the colum header.

Here we go:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.free-date', function(e) {
  $(".btn-success").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

});
```

```css
.btn-success {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-success.selected {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="flex-fill w-100 table-bordered">
  <!--    -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 25%">Time</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%">Employee 1</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%">Employee 2</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%">Employee 3</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        09:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        09:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:30:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        10:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        10:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:30:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        11:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        11:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:30:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        12:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        12:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        13:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        13:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        14:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        14:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        15:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        15:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        16:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        16:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        17:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        17:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The code is dynamically generated with PHP (I use a Controller in Laravel).

When showing the table, I also pass a time slot which can be like 0:15h 0:30h 1:00h etc. 
I want to achieve to show the (needed) slot for a booking via css.
This means when somebody has a time slot with 01:00h and he click on 09 o'clock the column for 09:00 and 09:30 should (for example) change the background-attribute. 
So that the user can see his reserved time span on the calendar- table.
This should be dynamic, this means when user clicks on 09 o clock it should set the background for 09:00 and 09:30. When he clicks on 10 o clock it should set the background for 10:00 and 10:30 -> the old selection for 09:00 and 09:30 should not be visible anymore.

I tried following:

**- colspan:**
Did not work out, as the cells moved all the way. Could be too much logic for hiding the moved cells and span the clicked cell.

**- use a div with position=absolute and set the height over JQuery:**
Had the problem that the div with the position=absolute was just off space all the time. Think that's a pretty good solution, but need some more knowledge to get it done, maybe someone might help me out on this one.

At all .. I looked at the good old fullcalendar.. to see how it's getting done. 
Seems that the fullcalendar also making use of the position:absolute with calculating the height / width.

Maybe someone got me a good / clean solution or an hint for this one?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers Greg

Answer (score 0):

You may search for index position to apply the same rules to the next row to the child at the same index.

example

```js
$(document).on("click", ".free-date", function(e) {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  $(".btn-success").removeClass("selected");
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .parent() //climb up to the parent row
    .next() // go to next row
    .children().eq(index) // every child with the same index
    .addClass("selected").html('booked');
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected").html('booked');
});
```

```css
.btn-success {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-success.selected {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="flex-fill w-100 table-bordered">
  <!--    -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 25%">Time</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%">Employee 1</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%">Employee 2</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 25%">Employee 3</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        09:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        09:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:30:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 09:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 10:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        10:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        10:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:30:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 10:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 11:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        11:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        11:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:30:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 11:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 12:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        12:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-info btn-reserved" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:00:00">
        <div class="booked-date text-center">booked</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        12:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 12:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 13:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        13:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        13:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 13:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 14:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        14:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        14:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 14:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 15:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        15:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        15:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 15:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 16:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        16:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        16:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 16:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 17:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        17:00

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:00:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:00:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        17:30

      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="1" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="2" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>
      <td class="btn-success" data-employeeid="3" data-startdate="2019-11-16 17:30:00" data-enddate="2019-11-16 18:30:00">
        <div class="free-date text-center">free</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[codepen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYYQVQW)

Comment: Since i cannot upvote (public), because I'm new here: It works like a charm. Thank you! Great solid / simple solution! Regards